# Grub Rescue prompt after 12.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, grub2, 12.10, grubrescue

Dual boot HP desktop that had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 working fine until yesterday.

Upgraded to 12.10 and the grub install gave an error of not being able to write to the boot sector. It looks like the situation is similar to the one in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1053793).

Here is the pastebin from an unsuccessful boot-repair - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1290132/

Not booting at all now and goes back to grub rescue all the time.

Can someone help so that the system shall start booting again?

Comment: the LDM situation that grub was complaining about made me uninstall Ubuntu altogether !

Comment: @K.KPatel: With all due respect, if you look at the timestamps of both the questions your question is the duplicate of this one, sir.

Answer (score 1):

boot from a live USB, install and run the software called boot-repair.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

it should fix it automatically for you.

Comment: The boot-info script result linked to from the question is from an unsuccessful run of boot-repair - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1290132/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a couple of times, when there is insufficient space before the boot partition for Grub to be installed. I just backed up this partition then deleted it, then recreated it with more space in front.

```
update-grub and grub-install
```

needs to be executed to get it working again afterwards.